# Write Test Annotations for Framework

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, frameworks, annotations, automated-tests

I was looking for some examples how to create annotations for my Framework, but didn't find.
May be somebody can give me an example how to create @BeforeClass, @AfterClass, and @Test annotations for my framework (based on Selenium on Java).
Or gime me some link where I can read about this.
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I'm giving you the code in pictures, since you aim to write your own fwk.***

**1. You will need some annotation to start with. E.g. like this:**

[image]

**2. You will need test method launcher and annotation processor, let's start from a class.**

[image]

**3. Now create some test class that will work with your micro test fwk.**

[image]

**4. And also a global runner of all your stuff with main method**

[image]

Output when you launch RunnerClass:

> This is mah test one
>
> This is mah test two

**But to hell with this, just use TestNG, it is a pretty good framework for all your needs.**